# How to get the difference between two dates in hours, minutes and seconds.?

Tags: python, date

I have taken two dates as

```
import datetime
data1 = datetime.datetime.now()
data2 = datetime.datetime.now()
```

I have done it like this, I'm getting minutes and seconds. I want hours too; how can I do this?

My code:

```
diff = data2-data1
divmod(diff.days * 86400 + diff.seconds, 60)
(3, 45)
```

How can I get hours too? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What have you tried? What is `c`? What are the two dates (if both `now`, how big a difference are you expecting?!) Have you read the [docs on `timedelta`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#timedelta-objects)?

Comment: @jonrsharpe, Sorry for my spell mistake i have corrected it

Comment: @tripleee, That is another way my requirement is differentiating with `datetime.datetime.now`

Answer (score 67, accepted):

Finally found solution

```
import datetime
data1 = datetime.datetime.now()
data2 = datetime.datetime.now()

diff = data2 - data1

days, seconds = diff.days, diff.seconds
hours = days * 24 + seconds // 3600
minutes = (seconds % 3600) // 60
seconds = seconds % 60

print hours,minutes,seconds
```

Comment: `total_mins = (diff.days*1440 + diff.seconds/60)` to get the difference in minutes

Comment: there is a `total_seconds()` defined so you can just use `hours = diff.total_seconds() / 3600`

Comment: ` total_seconds() ` overflows if time differance is over a few days. @Avishek solution is better because it does not overflow over a month.